# How to integrate native app code in ionic1 codova project?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-v1

I have AR (Augmented reality) demo app in native code both iOS and Android.  I want to integrate this app in my existing ionic cordova project.  My Ionic project is build in Ionic v1 with Cordova and Angular 1.5.3.  As I'm new to ionic development I would seek proper guidance and help in this forum.  Attached my ionic info.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hi, this is a broad open-ended question which is not suitible for this site. Your questions should be reasonably scoped. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to convert the native code to a cordova plugin. This is the only way a ionic/cordova app get's access to native code.

This is too big to describe in detail here and here's the link to Cordova's plugin guide.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/